# Capybara emails: setting correct port in URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

I'm using Capybara (2.4.4) with the capybara-email (2.4.0) gem in RSpec (2.14.1) integration tests for my Rails (4.1.6) app. I have a test that ensures the functionality of a link in an email. While Capybara spawns its server on different, random ports each test run, Rails's path helpers in the email views always generate the `localhost:3000` domain as specified in my `config/environments/test.rb`.

How can I specify that the Rails path helpers use the current Capybara test server's host and port for domains?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by specifying the host (but not the port) in `test.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost' }
```

and including

```
Capybara.always_include_port = true
```

in env.rb.